# MNIST - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist

I have a problem with my code when i am going to use mnist dataset
it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ati\Desktop\GD\GD.py", line 306, in <module>
update_interval=update_interval, max_prob=max_prob, plot=plot, train=train, gpu=gpu)
File "C:\Users\Ati\Desktop\GD\GD.py", line 105, in main
images, labels = dataiter.next()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

i think problem is related to this part of my code:

```
 transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                          transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),
                          ])
dataset = MNIST(root='root', download=True , transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
images, labels = images.view(-1, 784) / 255, labels)
```

could someone gives me a help on this please

Comment: Why don't you do `print(dataiter.next())` and find out what it returns, because it clearly isn't a two-tuple.

Comment: Not the cause of your error...but the `ToTensor` transform already converts your image from range [0,255] to range [0,1]. Then the `Normalize` transform puts the data in the range [-1,1]. In the last line of your snippet you divide by 255 which will put the images in range [-1/255, 1/255] so you probably don't actually want to be dividing images by 255.

Comment: thanks @ FiddleStix , i did what you said and wondering that it showd me only two arrays of 28*28 pixels in another word only two images were showing....should i use a loop for `dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()`

Comment: thanks @ jodag for your response....although it did not solve my problem but u hint good point...:)